# k8s on mesos scheduler.log?

Tags: kubernetes, mesos

[image: scheduler.log]

Something happend in my production environment.

-rw-rw-r--  1 root root 1628363775 Feb 22 14:06 scheduler.log

Answer (score 1):

Theres isn't a single error in that log; it looks perfectly healthy. What would you like to know about it?

Comment: The log incress quickly and I  considerd some errors occured,  thanks a lot

Comment: For future reference, the first character of each log line indicates its severity. "I" indicates that it's just an "INFO" message, or that nothing is wrong. "W" means "WARNING", which means that something minor or insignificant might have gone wrong, but it's not a big deal. "E" means "ERROR", which can mean that something bad or unexpected has happened. Unless it starts with an "E", it's nothing to worry about, and even then it often isn't unless the developers were very strict when writing their logging statements.